# Image sprites for website

Tags: html, css, css-sprites, mockups

Is it better to use image sprites for CSS or use a lot of different image files?
Maybe it is better to use a lot of different images rather than one sprite or vice versa?

Comment: by creating new transparent image which consist of all the images using photoshop or image editing tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As typical website contains multiple css, java script and image files,causing browser to request multiple http requests. By using sprite it causes less http requests (good for webserver and client/user), and so page will be load fast (good for client/user)

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in 1 sprite, so only 1 request is needed.

EDIT

Actually it's best to put everything that's related on the same sprite, for example a sprite with forum images, a sprite with homepage images, ...
Since you don't need the forum images on the homepage. (-> reduce size of request)